# Python update last line of file (stdout)

Tags: python, file

In Python program, I am redirecting `stdout` using below:

```
sys.stdout = open("log_file.txt", "a",0)
```

On certain condition I want rewrite the last line of the file.

I have tried below:

```
if (status=='SAME'):
  print '\r'+'Above status doesnot change and last checked @'+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())),
```

This seems to work when I look at file using tail command.

```
tail -f log_file.txt
```

However when the I look at the original content of the file, it is not overwriting the last line but it is appending.

Please suggest me any other approaches keeping `sys.stdout = open("log_file.txt", "a",0)` as is.

My code is Producing output as :

```
0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W-> Started   : 2016-06-14 16:15:32
0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W@HiveScript                               RUNNING   job_1465907358342_1346 RUNNING    -
Above status doesnot change and last checked @2016-06-14 16:15:43.096288 
Above status doesnot change and last checked @2016-06-14 16:15:53.344065 
Above status doesnot change and last checked @2016-06-14 16:16:03.672789 
0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W@end                                      OK        -                      OK         -
```

I want it to be

```
 0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W-> Started   : 2016-06-14 16:15:32
 0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W@HiveScript                               RUNNING   job_1465907358342_1346 RUNNING    - 
 Above status doesnot change and last checked @2016-06-14 16:16:03.672789 
 0007505-160614083053377-oozie-oozi-W@end                                      OK        -                      OK         -
```

Comment: If you don't want to append, don't open it with "a".

Comment: i want to append in some scenarios, but if a condition comes I want to overwrite the last line.. In my case if status doesnot change I want overwrite the last line with last checcked timestamp. If it changes I want to append the new status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually running a test case, I'd try:

- `open` the file in `append` mode
- read lines, noting the file position at the start of each line
- after reading the last line, use `seek` to move back to the start of that line
- `write` the new text (make sure it is at least as long as the original).
- `close` the file

===================

```
from __future__ import print_function  # for 2.7
f = open('log.txt', mode='r+')   # for preexisting file
for i in range(10):
    ref = f.tell()
    print('%s line %s'%(i,ref), file=f)
    if (i % 3)==0:
        f.seek(ref)
        print('%s oops %s'%(i,ref), file=f)
ref = f.tell()
print('ending at %3d'%100, file=f)
f.seek(ref)
print('ending at %3d'%f.tell(), file=f)
f.close()
```

produces:

```
2200:~/mypy$ cat log.txt
0 oops 0
1 line 9
2 line 18
3 oops 28
4 line 38
5 line 48
6 oops 58
7 line 68
8 line 78
9 oops 88
ending at  98
```

In 2.7 this form also works:

```
sys.stdout = f
for i in range(10):
    ref = f.tell()     # or ref = sys.stdout.tell()
    print '%s line %s'%(i,ref)
    if (i % 3)==0:
        f.seek(ref)
        print '%s oops %s'%(i,ref)
```

Comment: the file is created while job is running, by redirecting stdout to file. So are you suggesting me whenever i hit the condition, stop redirecting stdout to file, read the file, seek back to last position and write it , close it and again redirect output to file.

Comment: I just did some experimenting.  If I open the file with 'r+' mode I can `readline`, `tell`, `seek` and `write` (or `print(...,file=f)`).  Since I was in an interactive shell I did not try a `stdout` redirect.  But I can test the write without closing using a separate open/read (with `ipython` `%cat`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate class like this:

```
class OverwiteLogger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = "filename.txt"

    def write(self, message):
        f = open(self.filename, "r")
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines[-1] = message
        open(self.filename, 'w').writelines(lines)
        f.close()
```

And use it like:

```
logger = OverwriteLogger()
sys.stdout = open('filename.txt', 'a', 0)
if (status=='SAME'):
    logger.write('Above status doesnot change and last checked @'+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())))
else:
    print status
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the only way you're going to be able to do it is if you read the whole file and print each line, except the last line, back into the log. Not terribly efficient but it should work.